# Can not backup multiple (not all) databases Ola Hallengren

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

This error is quite easy to replicate. So before I send a bug to Ola, I'd like to check if maybe I'm doing it wrong. Version is 2018-06-27 20:44:12

I created 3 databases. DB1, DB2 and DB3. I'd like to backup these 3 databases only in this script independently of what other databases exists. According to Ola's homepage, this is the way I interpret it to be written for the `@Databases` parameter.

### Here is the syntax

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = DB1, DB2, DB3,
@Directory = N'C:\Temp',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'N',
--@CleanupTime = 360,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y',
@NumberOfFiles = 4
```

I get error:

> Msg 119, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Must pass parameter number 2 and
>   subsequent parameters as '@name = value'.      After the form '@name =
>   value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the
>   form '@name = value'.

I've tried

- @Databases = DB1, @Databases = DB2, @Databases = DB3, but then I get error - Parameter '@Databases' was supplied multiple times.
- I've tried using ; instead of , but still error.
- Tried [DB1] etc, also error.
- Tried N', also error

I'm trying to accomplish line 7 on the picture below from [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) 
[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi.
I understand why this post is put on hold. I can't reframe. So if anyone with permission rights can move this topic to a better place then go ahead please. It can also be deleted since it was a really (too?)simple problem, and will probavly not be of assistance for the broader public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the code for [DatabaseBackup.sql](https://ola.hallengren.com/scripts/DatabaseBackup.sql), you'll see that the definition for the parameter `@Databases` is `@Databases nvarchar(max) = NULL`.  When passing in literals like `DB1, DB2, etc.`, the entire string needs to be surrounded by single quotes - (just like you used for literals for other parameters).

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'DB1, DB2, DB3',
@Directory = N'C:\Temp',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'N',
--@CleanupTime = 360,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y',
@NumberOfFiles = 4
```